# Make whole panel draggable in dashboard

Tags: primefaces

I have a dasbhoard with panels, these are only draggable with the header. But on the http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dnd/draggable.xhtml page the first panel is draggable from the whole panel. Is it possible to also implement it in the dashboard panels. I tried adding the `<p:draggable for="id" />` for the panels, but the dashboard and the rest of the website beneath the dashboard wouldn't load anymore.

Comment: Search StackOverflow. 'Deja-vu'... (but might also be that the PrimeFaces forum contains a solution)

Comment: I've already searched and couldn't find anything, that's why I posted it here.

Comment: But you did not mention that (as stated in the [ask] page)... What is weird is that I cannot find it either anymore, but a part of it does show up in the 'Hottest 'PrimeFaces Answers' of stackoverflow from december 2015: _"
30 dec. 2015 - As you're using PrimeFaces, you'll have jQuery at hands. .... right, basically it comes down to the handle property being hardcoded in the JS PrimeFaces.widget."_ I'll try to find it and mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: found it... by using text from the comment above... weird it does not show up normally. Will improve that Q and A so it does

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to find it.

Comment: I'm also glad I found it, Now I'm at least certain I'm not loosing my mind due to Korsakov or Alzheimer

Comment: please upvote the other Q and A, I've seen them float up in google to (and no, it does not give **me** additional reputation, so no self-interest here ;-)